# MYSQL penetrance from more subqueries

Tags: mysql

Please can you help where is the problem.

**MYSQL**

```
Select NameList_name from NameList where NameList.id In  
(Select NameList.id from NameList where id_company = 
(Select company.id From company where company_company Like "XY"))
And
(Select id_NameList from NameListGoods where id_NameListGoodsKind = 
(Select NameListGoodsKind.id from NameListGoodsKind where NameListGoodsKind_NameListGoodsKind LIKE "XX"))
And
(Select id_NameList from NameListStateFrom where id_StateFrom = 
(Select StateFrom.id from StateFrom where StateFrom_state Like "XXX"))
And
(Select id_NameList from NameListStateTo where id_StateTo = 
( Select StateTo.id from StateTo where StateTo_state Like "XYX"));
```

This returned me ""*SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value*""
strong text
I want to search in:
Select NameList_name from NameList where NameList.id
The right NameList.id penetrance
what is returned from others subquery.

Example:

Table Namelist:

```
ID   Name    
1    a   
2    b    
3    c    
4    d    
5    e
```

**subquery1 :**

```
(Select NameList.id from NameList where id_company = 
(Select company.id From company where company_company Like "XY"))
```

Return me : numbers : 1,4,5

**subquery2 :**

```
(Select id_NameList from NameListGoods where id_NameListGoodsKind = 
(Select NameListGoodsKind.id from NameListGoodsKind where NameListGoodsKind_NameListGoodsKind LIKE "XX"))
```

Return me : numbers 2,4,3

**subquery3 :**

```
(Select id_NameList from NameListStateFrom where id_StateFrom = 
(Select StateFrom.id from StateFrom where StateFrom_state Like "XXX"))
```

Return me : numbers 3,4,1

**subquery4 :**

```
(Select id_NameList from NameListStateTo where id_StateTo = 
(Select StateTo.id from StateTo where StateTo_state Like "XYX"));
```

Return me : numbers 5,4,2,1

**Head Query**

Penetrance from this results is number 4.Then i need to show me the Name from Namelist where Namelist.id=4;

Thx for help,

Comment: Incidentally, SQL (especially MySQL) is notoriously poor at handling these sorts of nP problems.

Comment: Quick fix: change all `=` to `in`

Comment: Shadow : Quick fix i try but result ist "SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value"

Comment: Then you have not changed all `=` to `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM (SUBQUERY 1) a
  JOIN (SUBQUERY 2) b
    ON b.id = a.id
  JOIN (SUBQUERY 3) c
    ON c.id = a.id
  JOIN (SUBQUERY 4) d
    ON d.id = a.id;
```